# Adium Transcripts are stored with messages colored white

Tags: mac, adium

My chat transcripts are stored correctly, but when I open them up the other person's chat messages are all wrapped with a span turning their message white.

```
<message sender="sip:user@foo.com" time="2016-10-13T16:57:53-0700" alias=""><div><span style="color: ##000000; font-family: Lucida Grande; font-size: 12pt;">FOO</span></div></message>
```

This makes it so that when I try to view transcripts in the Adium transcript window I cannot see the other side's messages.

I am using Adium 15.10 on Mac with SIP plugin for Office Communicator.